# When do we use tell+infinitive with to ? (Not tell + object + to)

Tags: infinitives, transitivity, ditransitive-verbs

I'm looking for an example of using 'tell + infinitive with to'.
My book said 'tell' can be used with infinitive to, but didn't give me an example. I think that it generally comes 'tell+object+infinitive to'. 
Can I say it as following?

> She told to go there.

Or

> She was told to go there.

Please give me any reasonable example.

Comment: If your book doesn't give an example, it's just repeating rumors. Get a different book. _Tell_ is a bitransitive verb -- it has two objects. One is the indirect object -- the person that the subject tells something to, and the other is  the direct object -- what the subject tells that person.  The direct object can be an infinitive, **if** the subject of the infinitive verb is the same as the indirect object of _tell_. Like _I told him to leave_. That's [B-Equi](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf). _Tell_ doesn't allow A-Equi; it requires an indirect object.

Answer (score 3):

You use *tell* with an infinitive when *tell* means "to request or command."

> Tell him to stop.

When *tell* is expressed in passive voice, the direct object is not needed, because the person being told is the same as the subject.

> She was told to stop.

If we need to say who is doing the telling, *by X* can be used.

> She was told to stop by Michael.

If *tell* is not in passive voice, then omitting the direct object sounds weird, because it leaves the question "tell who?" unanswered.

> Tell to stop.  (Tell who?)